# Can I use jQuery for Mongoose promises?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongoose, promise

Is this working as expected?

```
$.when(model.UserModel.findOne(criteria).exec());
```

It works fine if it throws no error (document is found or empty), but will it also handle mongoose error correctly?

Comment: You're using jQuery on the back end?

Comment: There is a node module and it keeps the code consistent with the fronted, I also parse some 3rd party websites using jQuery in the backend. Since this is a private project I will not switch to Q promises for now, even if I see the advantages - just learning all the stuff yet :)